# All four corner of a view having different radius

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

How do i design a UIView whose all 4 corners have different corner radius.  So, UIView with its top right corner radius of 20, top left corner radius of 30, bottom left corner radius of 10 and bottom right corner radius of 20

[image: VIEW HIERARCHY]

I want to add different cornerRadius to Viw Container shown in image.
using UIBEZIER method cuts off the share comment and like portion.
viw Container is pinned to cell

Comment: Here's a link to a blog with an easy answer - provided you are targeting iOS 11+ : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/masked-and-animated-corners/

Answer (score 8):

You can use this UIView extension. It will create and apply a mask layer according to your radius values.

```
extension UIView {
func applyRadiusMaskFor(topLeft: CGFloat = 0, bottomLeft: CGFloat = 0, bottomRight: CGFloat = 0, topRight: CGFloat = 0) {

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - topRight, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft, y: 0))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: topLeft), controlPoint: .zero)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height - bottomLeft))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: bottomLeft, y: bounds.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - bottomRight, y: bounds.height))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height - bottomRight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: topRight))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - topRight, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0))

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = path.cgPath
    layer.mask = shape
}
}
```

Example usage:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.backgroundColor = .red
view.applyRadiusMaskFor(topLeft: 80, bottomLeft: 40, bottomRight: 30, topRight: 60)
```

Result: [Radius applied image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4JeX.png)

Comment: Don't forget to call this function every time the view resizes.

Comment: I used this with my view but the problem is cuts off the bottom portion of my view works fine with top left and top right. @aleksmutlu

Comment: Are you resizing the view after applying the mask? Like @Samah said, you need to re-apply the mask for every size change.

Comment: If you are using autolayout, try calling layoutIfNeeded() before applying the mask. theViewYouApplyMask.layoutIfNeeded() theViewYouApplyMask.applyRadiusMaskFor(... @NikeshHyanju

Comment: nope tried and failed ! i cant seem to get it right i have used different other methods but what ever i do it always cuts off the bottom section

Comment: @aleksmutlu btw this view i am trying to add this corner radius is inside a table view cell does that change anyhing ?

Comment: @NikeshHyanju How do you layout your cell? In storyboard or by code using frames?

Comment: @aleksmutlu  it’s in storyboard

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your cell hierarchy? @NikeshHyanju

Comment: @aleksmutlu please revisit my question.